# Validate data against file output c#

Tags: c#, bdd, specflow

I have multiple csv files. These csv files will be populated once my batch commands are executed. I'm using specflow BDD.

I'm writing code for my 'Then' step. The approach i'm taking is in my feature file i've used an Example table to state the different types of status (see below). I'm having trouble writing code that will execute a file path and then validate it again my expected data.

So Below i've written code for my Then step. I have stated the processFilePath which states the path of where my file will be. I want to now put a piece of code that will be able to cat the processFilePath and path which contains multiple file names. So for example xxx_ccx.csv.ovrr,xxx_bbx.csv.ovrr,xxx_aax.csv.ovrr.

Once the file has been processed i want to then validate my results.

```
        [Then("Transfer measure should be generated for (.*)")]

    public void ValidateMeasurement(string path, string expected)
    {
        const string processFilePath = "/orabin/app/product/ff/actuals/";
        var actual = Common.LinuxCommandExecutor
                           .RunLinuxcommand($"cat {processFilePath}{path}");
```

Below is the file name and expected output i'd expect. How can i put a validation in place so when i cat the file below the output can be validated against the expected output data.

```
("xxx_txrbf_xxxx.csv.ovr", "6677,6677,1001,6"),
            ("xxx_tsxbf_xxxx.csv.ovrr", "6677,6677,3001,6"),
            ("xxx_tzxbf_xxxx.csv.ovrr", "6677,6677,2001,6")]")


 Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all.

Paths should be handled by DirectoryInfo in C#.

And Files should be retrieved  via DirectoryInfo, to hold FileInfo classes.

Makes it so easy to handle files, and searching for files etc.

f.x.

```
 string expectedPath = @"C:\Expected";

        string path = @"C:\Test";
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles();
        DirectoryInfo diExpected = new DirectoryInfo(expectedPath);
        FileInfo[] expectedFiles = diExpected.GetFiles();

        for (int index = 0; index < files.Length; index++)
        {
            FileInfo currentFile = files[index];
            FileInfo currentExpectedFile = expectedFiles[index];
            //Expected data, should match "index" data location.
            Assert.AreEqual(currentFile.FullName, currentExpectedFile.FullName);

            //If you want to assert content:
            string actualContent = File.ReadAllText(currentFile.FullName);
            string expectedContent = File.ReadAllText(currentExpectedFile.FullName);
            Assert.AreEqual(actualContent, expectedContent);

        }
```

I am not familiar with the BBD and specflow content, but I assume you are able to modify my example to adhere to your requirements? 
so that the content of your expected files will match the content of your actual results from your:

```
var actual = Common.LinuxCommandExecutor
                           .RunLinuxcommand($"cat {processFilePath}{path}");
```

command.

You should also do an Assert that your expected files count is the same as your actual files count.